# Drawing text as textures on squares does not show anything

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, augmented-reality, texture2d

I'm new to OpenGL and I'm developing an Augmented-reality application for Android.

Until now, I was drawing white squares, perpendicular to the camera, pointing the user to the direction where a "Point of interest" would be.

Now, I'm trying to show some text into the squares.

I've read a lot and it seems that creating a texture with the text is the most direct and easiest approach, so I'm creating the textures as soon as I get data of the Points of interest and stick them to their squares. For that, I use bitmaps.

Let's see some code. Within my onDrawFrame method, I do something like this:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        // Get sensors matrix
                ...


        //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Load remapped matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);



        // List of Points of interest (modified when some data is downloaded)
        synchronized (poiList) {

            if(mNewData){  // True if new data has been dowloaded)
                if(textures != null)  // Delete old textures
                    gl.glDeleteTextures(textures.length, textures, 0);

                textures = loadGLTexture(gl, soapPoiList.getPoiList());
                mNewData = false;
            }

            int i = 0;
            // Iterate the list
            for (PointOfInterest c : poiList) {

                         gl.glLoadIdentity();
                 gl.glLoadMatrixf(remappedRotationMatrix, 0);

                 // Get bearing
                             ...

                 // Place polygon in the right place
                 gl.glRotatef(-bearing, 0, 0, 1);
                 gl.glTranslatef(0, ICONS_SIZE_RATIO, 0);

                         // Actually draws the polygon with text
                 c.draw(gl, textures[i]);

                 i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where loadGLTextures is:

```
protected int[] loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, List<PointOfInterest> l){
    int res[] = new int[l.size()];
    gl.glGenTextures(res.length, res, 0);
    int i = 0;

    for(PointOfInterest p : l) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        bitmap.eraseColor(Color.BLACK);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(35);
        textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        // Draw the text centered
        canvas.drawText(Float.toString(p.getDinstanceToOrigin()) + " m.", 10,35, textPaint);

        // Bind the texture to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, res[i]);

        //  Create Nearest Filtered Texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        bitmap.recycle();

        i++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

It basically creates a bitmap for each Point of Interest, and generate a texture with it. The texture will be applied over a white square later, as it is shown in this class:

```
    public class PointOfInterest {

        // MEMBERS ----------------------------------------------------------------
            ....
            ....

        // OpenGL necessary variables
        /** The buffer holding the vertices */
        private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

        /** The initial vertex definition */
        private float vertices[] = { 
                                    -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, //Bottom Left   V1
                                    -1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, //Top Left      V2
                                     1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, //Bottom Right  V3
                                     1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, //Top Right     V4
                                   };

        private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
        private float texture[] = {
                                    0.0f, 0.0f,     // V1
                                    1.0f, 0.0f,     // V3
                                    0.0f, 1.0f,     // V2
                                    1.0f, 1.0f      // V4
        };

        // CONSTRUCTORS -----------------------------------------------------------

        public PointOfInterest(Location originLocation){
            currentLocation = originLocation;

            mPoiLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
            byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

            vertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);

            byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
            byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

            textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
            textureBuffer.put(texture);
            textureBuffer.position(0);
        }

        // PUBLIC METHODS ---------------------------------------------------------

        public void draw(GL10 gl, int textureId){
            // Bind the previously generated texture
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

            // Point to our buffers
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

            // set the colour for the square
            //gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

            //Set the face rotation
            gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

            //Point to our vertex buffer
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

            //Draw the vertices as triangle strip
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

            //Disable the client state before leaving
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        }

        ....
        ....
}
```

I have tried to map the texture as it is taught [here](http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/) and [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html) with no success. I really don't know what to do to get some letters drawn on the squares and am really lost here... Maybe the text is being drawn on the other face of the square, maybe the textures are not being generated... I don't know.

Any kind of help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere? You say you are new to openGL. If you copied it, then probably you missed something in the process.

Comment: I did a very simple example that works. Just an static square with a texture with text on it. Now, I'm adapting that example to my application. I have checked hundred of times if I have missed something but I see nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I had forgotten to enable texture mapping. You can do that within any method that uses the GL10 object. I prefer to do it within the draw method of my objects, so any other object is not affected by the texture. It's as simple as this (just changed 2 lines, the ones that say NEW!!):

```
public void draw(GL10 gl, int textureId){
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);    //NEW !!! Enable Texture Mapping

    // Bind the previously generated texture
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    // Point to our buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // set the colour for the square
    //gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

    //Set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    //Point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    //Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);   ////NEW !!! Disable texture mapping
}
```