# Possible to draw a string ("Hello World") as a texture at run-time?

Tags: textures, webgl

I understand how to apply texture mapping to polygons.

But is it possible to create a texture of a string (like the current frames per second display) and map it to a polygon(s), all at run-time?

**Updated**

This could possibly work. I'll have to test this out for myself.
[Drawing text as textures on squares does not show anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418796/drawing-text-as-textures-on-squares-does-not-show-anything?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating textures at runtime is easy with the 2D canvas API

```
var gl = someCavnasInThePage.getContext("webgl");

// create an offscreen canvas with a 2D canvas context
var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");

// make it a desired size 
ctx.canvas.width = 128;
ctx.canvas.height = 64;

// fill it a certain color
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";  // red
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

// draw some text into it.
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)";  // yellow
ctx.font = "20px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText("Hello World", 5, 40);

// Now make a texture from it
var tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ctx.canvas);

// generate mipmaps or set filtering 
gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
```

Here's a working example

```js
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var gl = twgl.getWebGLContext(document.getElementById("c"));
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

var arrays = {
  position: [1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
  normal:   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1],
  texcoord: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  indices:  [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23],
};
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);


var tex = createTextTexture(gl, "Hello World", 256, 128);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

  var fieldOfView = Math.PI * 0.25;
  var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  var projection = m4.perspective(fieldOfView, aspect, 0.0001, 500);
  var radius = 5;
  var eye = [
    Math.sin(time) * radius,
    2,
    Math.cos(time) * radius];
  var target = [0, 0, 0];
  var up = [0, 1, 0];
  var camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  var view = m4.inverse(camera);

  var worldViewProjection = m4.multiply(view, projection);
  var uniforms = {
    u_worldViewProjection: worldViewProjection,
  };
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

var ctxForMakingTextures;
function createTextTexture(gl, str, width, height) {
    // create an offscreen canvas with a 2D canvas context
    if (!ctxForMakingTextures) {
       ctxForMakingTextures = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
    }
    var ctx = ctxForMakingTextures;
    
    // make it a desired size 
    ctx.canvas.width = width;
    ctx.canvas.height = height;
    
    // fill it a certain color
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";  // red
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    
    // draw some text into it.
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)";  // yellow
    ctx.font = "40px sans-serif";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World", 5, 40);
    
    // Now make a texture from it
    var tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ctx.canvas);
    
    // generate mipmaps or set filtering 
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    
    return tex;
};
```

```css
html, body, canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script id="vs" type="not-js">
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;
    
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;

void main() {
   gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
   v_texcoord = texcoord;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="fs" type="not-js">
precision mediump float;
    
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
</script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to display text in 3D using OpenGL. Here are a few options you should consider:

1. Create a regular rectangular texture with the text you wish to display, and render it on a simple 4-vertex rectangle. This is the simplest implementation, but it will require you to generate a different texture for every string you want to display.
2. As above, create a rectangular texture, but this time, make one for every letter / character you wish to be able to support. Then, build a factory which generates 4-vertex rectangles for each letter in a certain string, choosing the appropriate letter for each shape. You'll need to work on good positioning a bit, but this will give you a fairly flexible solution.
3. Similar to #2, but this time, use some seamless texture, but generate shapes for each letter / character you wish to support. Each shape will hold multiple vertexes, and unless you use external graphic assets, it could take you some time to complete. However, this implementation would give you the most impressive method of displaying text, as each letter would appear as a 3-dimensional object in space.

Comment: im not sure this is what I want. I don't want to create a "factory" that creates fonts/letters using billboards/quads. What I want is: 1) Given a string which is determined at run-time, 2) create a texture, 3) apply to any polygon surface.

Comment: what you're describing doesnt sound like something "impossible", but it is definitely hard. You're asking to find a way to automatically generate a texture (bitmap) from a string, not very difficult, but then you want to find a way to map this in a good way to any polygon, and this is difficult. I'm sorry, but I don't think I can help you with this.